# C++11 move assignment operator for classes with objects as members - Beginner Level

Tags: c++11, move

I have a beginner question on the move assigment in c++11. Let say that I have a class A provided with a move assigment operator:

```
class A
{
 public:
   A();
  ~A();
  A& operator=(A&&);
  ...
}
```

I also have a class B containing a class A object and provided with a move assignment operator

```
class B
{
 public:
     B();
    ~B();
   B& operator=(B&&);
    ...
 private:
   A Test;
}
```

What I was thinking is that the B move assignment operator will call the move assignment operator of its member so I tried this method:

```
B& B::operator=(B&& Other)
{
  ...
  Test = Other.Test;
  ...
  return *this;
}
```

But this is not working since the move assignment of class A is not called.

Instead I was able to make the program work by using this method:

```
B& B::operator=(B&& Other)
{
  ...
  Test = std::move(Other.Test);
  ...
  return *this;
}
```

I do not understand why the first method is not working. I was thinking that since a constructor will call its members constructors the move assignment operator should do the same. Am I wrong or I made a mistake in my code? Can someone explain, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Other.Test` is not an rvalue expression since it has a name. OTOH `std::move(Other.Test)` has the type `A` and the value category xvalue (i.e., an rvalue). Thus, it can bind to the move constructor.

(EDIT : Shamelessly copied @dyp's comment. Thanks, @dyp and @KerrekSB.)

Comment: @dyp I don't understand. Is it incorrect to say that `std::move(Other.Test)` has type rvalue reference when I mean that it returns an rvalue reference?

Comment: @Pradhan: The correct statement is that "`std::move(Other.Test)` **is** an rvalue". Its type is `A`.

Comment: It is a quite pedantic remark; `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, but any reference-qualifier of the type of any expression is immediately dropped to form the value category. I.e., the expression `std::move(Other.Test)` has the type `A` and the value category *xvalue* (i.e., an *rvalue*).

Comment: @dyp: To be properly pedantic, you cannot "return a reference" (since indeed function calls are *expressions*). Rather, you can say that "the return type of `std::move` is an rvalue reference", or that "`std::move` returns an xvalue".

Comment: @KerrekSB You might be right, but I wonder whether *function returns type* is actually technical language. It occurs several times in the library part; but not in the core language part ("returns a ref") -- My `std::move` identifies a set of function templates, not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

@Pradhan is correct - you need to use `std::move` to move the members in the implementation of the move assignment operator. However, if that is all that is needed to implement your move constructor, then you can declare the operator to use the default implementation:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() : p{} { }
    ~A() { }

    A &operator=(A &&) = default;

    // Instead of:
    //    A &operator=(A &&other) {
    //        p = std::move(other.p);
    //        return *this;
    //    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A b;
    b = std::move(a);

    return 0;
}
```